# php get date from epoch ms

Tags: php, epoch

I have a field in ms from epoch, like 1350393140000.  I need to, in PhP, get this field as a datetime, change the time portion of it to 7AM (UTC time) and convert it back to ms from epoch.  How can I do this?

Comment: If you know the timezone of the timestamp, you can easily substract/add the difference to UTC.

Comment: @Veseliq: a unix timestamp is always in UTC. But how do you know the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$input = 1350393140000;

$dt = new DateTime('@' . floor($input / 1000));
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dt->modify('07:00');

$output = $dt->format('U') * 1000;
```

Comment: Wooops, ignore me, confused with a previous question!

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$ts = 1350393140000 / 1000;
$ts = mktime(7, date('i', $ts), date('s', $ts), date('n', $ts), date('j', $ts), date('Y', $ts));
$ts = $ts * 1000;
```

Comment: But indeed, you should use the DateTime class nowadays.